# Can I use the "Sabbath mode" on the refrigerator if it is not certified?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, appliances

We are looking to buy a new refrigerator that has a Sabbath mode. We noticed that both the GE Profile and Kitchenaid fridges have Sabbath modes, but the Kitchenaid is certified by the Star K and the GE Profile is not certified.

Are there any halachic problems with using the GE with it not being certified? Do they work differently? Or is it just as simple as Kitchenaid decided to pay Star K and GE didn't?

Comment: How would any of us have any idea how a random company built their appliances??? Motion to close as off topic.

Comment: @DoubleAA - My question was not requiring in-depth knowledge, here. Just an opinion from a few people who know. I accepted the answer given, already. If necessary, now that I have my answer, I can delete this question, completely, if you still feel it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike typical food certification, there is nothing exceptionally special about the Star-K certification of appliances. They look at the specifications and functions, and apply their Poskim's understanding of the application of Halacha.

The non-certified one can be shown to any Rabbi competent in that area and he can decide if the mode has any issues you should be concerned about. There is no unobserved process in the manufacture of the refrigerator that would require someone to know something confidential or to have been there during the manufacturing of the fridge in order to say it is fit for this use.

So they may work differently, and there is some chance that the Star-K looked at the GE model and refused to certify it, but the most likely scenario is that GE simply didn't see the marketing value in being certified, and Kitchenaid did.

Comment: Not everything is visible to the eye. I once saw a kitchenaid fridge, with a uncertified Shabbos Mode. Didn't do much except for turning off the display. No effect on the light, or the sensors.

Comment: @user if you could see that, so could anyone, which is the point of my answer.

Comment: I wasn't arguing with your answer. I just wanted to point out that you need to read the technical specs to understand what is or isn't happening.